# how to add customer validator in rails's model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know ActiveRecord provide some macros like `validates_uniqueness_of` `validates_size_of`
to do some validation for the user input. but I'm wondering whether it is possible to provide
some call-back like validation method to be used as a cutomised validation method in the model level. for example,
I want to check the input string only consits of letters from 'a' to 'h', funny? but it happened from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom functions with:

```
validate :custom_function

def custom_function
  ...
end
```

You can also use regular expressions to validate strings. For your example I would use:

```
validates_format_of :attribute, :with => /^[a-h]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

The [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods) has a good example of how to create your own custom validators. If you are using Rails 3 you could do it like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :from_a_to_h

  # Use the name of your attribute in place of :input and input.
  def from_a_to_h
    errors.add(:input, "must contain only letters from a to h") if input =~ /[i-Z]+/
  end
end
```